# pipenv на Ubuntu. ошибка: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pipenv==11.9.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: ubuntu, pipenv

Устанавливаю pipenv

```bash
$ pip install --user pipenv
$ which pipenv
#/usr/bin/pipenv
$ python -m site --user-base
#/home/maksim/.local
$ export PATH="$PATH:/home/maksim/.local/bin"
$ echo $PATH
#/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/maksim/.local/bin
$ pipenv --version

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')())
  File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .cli import cli
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .command import cli  # noqa
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pipenv.cli.options import (
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pipenv.project import Project
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pipenv.core import system_which
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pipenv.utils.resolver import venv_resolve_deps
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pipenv.vendor.requirementslib import Pipfile, Requirement
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3260, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/home/maksim/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 795, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pipenv==11.9.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: `pip3 install --user pipenv`?

Comment: @insolor Не помогло. Удалил, переустановил с помощью pip3. Тоже самое

Comment: Попробуйте еще python 3.10 грохнуть, потом через pip3 установить самую свежую версию pipenv (2022.7.4)